# Triggering a function on pressing enter in a char field odoo 14

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-14

Is it possible to trigger a function when the Enter key is pressed in the character field.?

The `onchange` function is not working as inside the function it returns another form.

From js i want to call function get_details of model customer.status.search  on clicking enter button

```
class CustomerStatusSearch(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'customer.status.search'

     def get_details(self):
        print("enter")
        for li in self:
            customer = self.env['res.partner'].search([('id', '=', 23)], limit=1)
          
           return {
                            'view_type': 'form',
                            'view_mode': 'form',
                            'view_id': self.env.ref('operation.view_registration_student_form').id,
                            'res_model': 'res.partner',
                            'target': 'current',
                            'res_id': customer.id,
                            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'
                        }
```

so is there any Javascript code for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new `Char` field to handle the `Enter` key event.

***Example:***

```js
odoo.define('Module_Name.FieldChar', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var FieldChar = require('web.basic_fields').FieldChar;
    var registry = require('web.field_registry');

    var FieldCharCustom = FieldChar.extend({
        _onKeydown: function (ev) {
            if (ev.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                // this._someFunction();
            }
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    });

    registry.add('char_custom', FieldCharCustom);

});
```

To load the js file, inherit the [web.assets_backed](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle):

```
<template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Module_Name/static/src/js/field_char.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Then you have just to set the `widget` attribute of a char field in the view arch:

```
<field name="name" widget="char_custom"/>
```

**Update**
You can use `this.rpc` to call `get_details` on `customer.status.search` model like they did when clicking a button to validate the [inventory](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/stock/static/src/js/inventory_validate_button_controller.js#L59-L82)

***Example:***

```
this._rpc({
    model: 'customer.status.search',
    method: 'get_details',
    args: [record_id]
        }).then(function (res) {
});
```

You can find an example in [init](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/stock/static/src/js/inventory_validate_button_controller.js#L18) method on how they get the inventory id from context

## Edit:

When you click for the first time in the custom char field the wizard record id will not be available and you can't call the `get_details` function because it depends on `self`. The `get_details` function does only return an action (open the partner form) which is also possible to do using the js code, just call `this.do_action` to execute the window action.

The fields values will be available in `this.recordData` variable if you use it to search for a particular partner.

If you try to open the partner form before saving, Odoo will show the following warning:

```
The record has been modified, your changes will be discarded. Do you want to proceed?
```

To avoid that you can simulate the click on the save button using:

```
$(".o_form_button_save").click();
```

***Example:***

```
odoo.define('MODULE_NAME.FieldChar', function (require) {
"use strict";
   var core = require('web.core');
   var _t = core._t;
   var FieldChar = require('web.basic_fields').FieldChar;
   var registry = require('web.field_registry');

   var FieldCharCustom = FieldChar.extend({
       _onKeydown: function (ev) {
           this._super.apply(this, arguments);
           if (ev.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
             var self = this;
             
             var customer_id = 14;
             
             $(".o_form_button_save").click();
             
             this._rpc({
                 model: 'ir.model.data',
                 method: 'xmlid_to_res_model_res_id',
                 args: ["base.view_partner_form"],
             }).then(function (data) {
               self.do_action(
                 {
                   name: _t('Customer Status'),
                   type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                   view_mode: 'tree,form',
                   res_model: 'res.partner',
                   target: 'current',
                   res_id: customer_id,
                   views: [[data[1], 'form'], [false, 'list']],
               });
             });
           }
       },
   });

   registry.add('char_custom', FieldCharCustom);

});
```

Comment: I want it only in a particular form....say model 'migrate.customer', when clicking enter in a field say 'location' it should trigger a function say migrate()

Comment: You have just to set the `widget` attribute of the location field  on a particular view.

Comment: showing error as this.get_details() is not a function

Comment: Please update your question and show the `get_details` function definition

Comment: You need to use `this.rpc` method, check my edit.

Comment: used that but  not working

Comment: Please show also the js code you have tried

Comment: The problem is that the form id is not getting,by clicking enter the form is not saving.so on clicking enter the form want to be saved and call the function

Comment: The `get_details` function is supposed to open the partner form. Do you want to close the wizard and open the partner form when you click enter in the char field? If so, use a button to open the partner form

Comment: Yes,Already have button there to open partner form.But i want this option also,on clicking enter it should direct to partner form

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, check the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

You use addEventListener 'keypress' then check if the keycode is the Enter key

```
document.getElementById('inputField').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            //Run a function here
        }
    });
```

Comment: needed only for this particular form

Comment: the idea is to replace the `document.getElementById('inputField')` with **your** specific form/input field/element @shahaludheenk

Comment: You can get that DOM element and just  do the addevent listener